# What would be the area of the shaded region?

Tags: geometry

I need to find the area of the shaded region in the diagram below. I used a geometry software with different measures for $AB$ and found out that there is a pattern for the shaded area, for example when $AB=10$ the area is $25$ and when $AB=20$ the area is $100$ and for $AB=30$ the area is $225$ and finally for $AB=40$ the area is $400$. But I don't really know how to calculate the shaded area.

[image]

Comment: **If** there is a fixed answer to this (i.e., the area is constant inspite of the degrees of freedom), we can look at the special case where $C=B$ and $E$ is on $AB$. Then $DFE$ becomes a right angled isosceles triangle with diagonal $10$. The area of that is clearly $25$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Even if there is a fixed answer (which is true) still we have to prove it.

Comment: From your examples $(\overline{AB}/2)^2$ would be an educated guess.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, And where could that come from?

Comment: Well, from the example values you've provided.  Also, I feel a smell of shearing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $P$ projection of $D$ onto $CF$. We have by Pythagoras' theorem:
$$CF \cdot (CP-PF)=(CP+PF)(CP-PF)=CP^2-PF^2=(CD^2-DP^2)-(FD^2-DP^2)=CD^2-FD^2=BC^2+BD^2-FD^2=BC^2$$
So we obtain the following system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
CP+PF=CF \\
CP-PF=\frac{BC^2}{CF}
\end{cases}$$
Subtracting second from the first and dividing by two we get that:
$$PF=\frac{CF-\frac{BC^2}{CF}}{2}=\frac{CF^2-BC^2}{2CF}=\frac{CA^2-BC^2}{2EF}=\frac{AB^2}{2EF}$$
Now, since the triangles $DEF$ and $PEF$ have the same base and equal heights they have to have the same area, therefore we have:
$$[DEF]=[PEF]=\frac{EF \cdot PF}{2}=\frac{AB^2}{4}$$
Plugging $AB=10$ we obtain $[DEF]=25$.

Comment: Excellent work, thank you very much.